# gstreamer webcam vp9enc lagging

Tags: go, webrtc, gstreamer

I have build a litte go webrtc project with a websocket signaling server and the webrtc part with pion.

But creating a vp8 or vp9 stream with gstreamer fails -> high latency

This is the pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=320,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! vp9enc ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

but the video is very laggy and there are some errors printed from gst

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(3003): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage: Output window was closed
Additional debug info:
../gst-plugins-base/sys/xvimage/xvimagesink.c(554): gst_xv_image_sink_handle_xevents (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage
Execution ended after 0:00:13.282962300
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

My computer is an i5 with 16G RAM ... there must be something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the equivalent for `vp9enc`, but check out these settings for [vp8enc](https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/blob/master/internal/gstreamer-src/gst.go#L48)

By default most encoders don't run at realtime speeds, so you have to set a few options. If you figure out the right vp9 options a PR would be great!

Comment: i have seen this properties, i am using this gst wrapper. I thought vp9 does not need them. However using the vp8enc pipeline with the written properties does not change anything

Comment: sry your right, the vp8 pipeline is ok. I had another issue trying vp8 some hours ago. The vp9 is better with the vp8 properties but fails if `error-resilient=partitions` is present, but the docs mention it

Comment: reported [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/rtpvp9depay-vp9dec-pipeline-crashes-when-a-single-RTP-packet-is-missed-td4685798.html)

Comment: Sorry I am not sure, that seems like a VPx/GStreamer bug. It might be easier to just use VP8 for now, I have heard some people avoiding VP9 for real-time because it is more 
CPU expensive.

Comment: yes I am using vp8 for now, it's running great. Have some trouble using the webrtc with srflx and not host (inside my lan) but thats another topic